# Flask Restful URLs giving 404 while in a blueprint

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I am trying to use Flask restful as a Blueprint in a pattern that works for other blueprints. I keep getting a 404 error when i go to 
/todos/1

My project setup is as follows:

**Folder structure**

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mod_api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── routes.py
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── base.html
│       └── home.html
├── config.py
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from config import config
bootstrap = Bootstrap()
api = Api()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    api.init_app(app)

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    from .mod_api import mod_api as api_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint)
    return app
```

**mod_api/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint

mod_api = Blueprint('mod_api', __name__)

from . import routes
```

**api/routes.py**

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from .. import api

class TodoItem(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        return {'task': 'Say "Hello, World!"'}

api.add_resource(TodoItem, '/todos/<int:id>')
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: have you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution is:

```
api.init_app(api_blueprint)
```